# Using for loop in apache poi

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

Im automating a database using apache poi. I need to get the sum of cell range `B3:H3`

I have successfully get the output. Now I need to loop the equation for 300+ rows. I used following equation for a single row.

```
sheet1.getRow(1).createCell(8).setCellValue("TOTAL");
sheet1.getRow(2).createCell(8).setCellFormula("SUM(B3:H3)");
```

I need to find the last row number and loop the process till then. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache POI rows number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963912/apache-poi-rows-number)

Comment: The duplicate doesn't seems to be the same but this what you should have find in a search engine and this holds some interesting way to iterate rows in  POI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int lastRow = sheet1.getLastRowNum()
```

You can get  the number of the last row contained in a sheet by using `getLastRowNum()` method.

Also please have a look at [`HSSFSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getPhysicalNumberOfRows--)

Comment: Is there any way to loop the process until that last row number? This is my very first java project so I don't have a proper idea about looping and I don't have enough time to study the basics.

Comment: You can iterate over rows and columns using for/forEach 
    
for (Row row : sheet1) {  ///iterate rows
    for (Cell cell : row) { // iterate columns in each row 
        // do something
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

There is a method available on `HSSFSheet` class

```
public int getLastRowNum()
```

[`HSSFSheet.getLastRowNum`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getLastRowNum--)

Comment: Is there any way to loop the process until that last row number? This is my very first java project so I don't have a proper idea about looping and I don't have enough time to study the basics.

Comment: Just use a standard for loop and use the `int` that got returned from `getLastRowNum()` as the terminating condition `for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); ++i)`